# Setting up a computer as a phone station via my router's telephone ports

Tags: router, asterisk, phone

First off, I should note that this is my first time working with telephone hard-/software beyond simply using a phone, plugging it in or setting up a router. In addition, I'm aware I could just use some kind of VoIP software in order to make calls from my PC, but that's not relevant to me, not only because I already have a phone provider and don't want to pay extra - my intention behind this project is more or less mostly professional curiousity being a software developer wishing to expand my knowledge ^^

That being said, what I would like to achieve is to be able to use my computer (and consequentially, any connected headset) as a telephone handset. It would be sufficient if I were able to either make or answer calls from my computer, but being able to do both would obviously be the preferred outcome. Background information: I live in Germany, my internet provider is the Telekom and I'm using their recommended router "Speedport Smart 3".

I hoped that achieving my goal would be as simple as plugging some kind of adapter card into my mainboard, connecting it to one of my router's telephone ports and installing some kind of software on my PC, but alas, it appears to be more complex.

So far, it seems to me that [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) is probably the way to go, combined with an [analog telephony interface card](https://www.asterisk.org/products/telephony-interface-cards). Unfortunately, it seems to me that Asterisk is a very basic framework that requires a lot of work to set up for my use case.
Therefore, I'm unable to tell if Asterisk would a) allow me to achieve my goal or, conversely, b) be overkill for my purpose.

If anyone knows whether

1. Asterisk can solve my issue and roughly how complicated that would be for a beginner in this field or
2. If not, what other solutions exist to achieve my goal,

I would greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: side note: the [tag:phone] tag states that questions about phones are off-topic here, but from reading a tag wiki, it seems to me that this is the case probably because most people using the tag abuse it for android or iPhone-specific questions. If my question is indeed considered off-topic as well, please feel free to delegate me to some other, more appropriate SE site (and if there is none, then I don't think this should be off-topic here :D)

Comment: I don’t see an actual question, I see you asking for users to share their experiences, but we are not a discussion forum and thus that isn’t allowed

Comment: @Ramhound I'm aware, I know the issue from RPG SE. I agree my question might be phrased unfortunately - what I want to know is whether Asterisk can solve my problem, or else how I can achieve my goal. The last paragraph asking people with experience to answer those questions is indeed superfluous, since that's the whole point of Stack Exchange ^^

Comment: Yet; Asking for our experiences is what makes it out of scope.

Comment: Go for IP phones and an online SIP provider. FAR far easier. You just need to setup the phones and the sip accounts.

Comment: @Ramhound I fail to see how my sub-questions as phrased in the (edited) last paragraph of my question are asking for people to narrate their experiences? Sure, obviously potential answerers should know what they're talking about (i.e. they should have some experience), but I'm not asking them to tell stories about how they accomplished similar things.

Comment: Your question is way too broad.